# How to add server tab in intellj Debugger

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've recently installed IntelliJ on a new pc and I don't have a server tab when i Debug/Run my web application.

[image]

Can you tell me how to reconfigure my IDEA so I get this tab there?

Update: My intelliJ edition is **Ultimate**

Comment: Try the **Restore Layout** button, it's hidden under `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this where I've floated the Server tab and then closed it (with the X on the top right). I think couldnt find any way to restore it in the current session.

What I did in the end was to stop the debugging session, cloes the debug tab altogether (Ctrl+F4 with the debug window selected) and then restarted IntelliJ.

That did the trick for me - the next time I debugged it the Server tab reappeared.